# Full Calendar JSON Demo not working

Tags: json, fullcalendar

I recently downloaded the Full Calendar program and was wondering what it requires to be installed on the server to work with JSON feeds. I tried running the json demo provided with the download but it does not fetch any events from the provided php file.

Thanks for any help

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  I am using Xampp and PHP is working on all our other pages.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem, but solving is quite easly, just check that json.html doesn't have headers set up correctly (in fact it doesn't have links to CSS nor JQuery or javascript files), just check that. A copy of my json.html is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../public/js/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../public/js/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css' media='print' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='../public/js/jquery/jquery-1.5.2.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='../public/js/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='../public/js/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

            editable: true,

            events: "json-events.php",

            eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
                alert(event.title + ' was moved ' + delta + ' days\n' +
                    '(should probably update your database)');
            },

            loading: function(bool) {
                if (bool) $('#loading').show();
                else $('#loading').hide();
            }

        });

    });

</script>
<style type='text/css'>

    body {
        margin-top: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
        }

    #loading {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        right: 5px;
        }

    #calendar {
        width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='loading' style='display:none'>loading...</div>
<div id='calendar'></div>
<p>json-events.php needs to be running in the same directory.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem as Dave and I do not quite understand your answer.Are you implying that there must not be any links to css/js files to the header section?If yes,why your page(that you display) has?

Comment: Hi Dimitris, responding your question: You have to add the header links (the ones with "link" and "script" tags) is the point I established, probably I got missed in the explaining. The thing here is that if you don't add them then the original problem from Dave appears, this is because it's required for the links to jquery and CSS to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

it calls a PHP file (json-events.php) so you need be running the example from a webserver that has php installed

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me once I set the timezone correct.

Add this to the json-events.php file:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```